# Error al generar un reporte de crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar generar un reporte hecho en crystal report desde C#, esta es una imagen del error.

[image: Error al momento de Generar el reporte]

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para llamar al reporte:

```
        frmReporteDescuentosFaltanInabima view = new frmReporteDescuentosFaltanInabima();
        ReportDocument report = new DescuentoParaGarante();
        DatosInabima dsInabima = new DatosInabima();

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(DB.CadenaConexion);
        cn.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select a.NOMBRE, a.CEDULA, a.DESCUENTO from NOMINA_INABIMA_LLEGO_APLICAR a " +
                                                   "where not exists(select * from NOMINA_APLICAR_INABIMA b where b.doc_identificacion = a.CEDULA)", cn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.Fill(dsInabima, "DESCUENTOS_FALTANTES");

            report.Load(RUTA_ARCHIVO+@\Reporte.rpt");
            report.SetDataSource(dsInabima);

            view.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
            view.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Pregunta tonta, pero tienes vinculado el data set al Crystal Reports correctamente, verdad? Puedes probar a rellenar un par de filas del dataset a mano y ver si te pasa también ese problema? Los mensajes de error de Crystal Reports en ocasiones son demasiado ambiguos.

Comment: @frikinside Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, ya he hecho la prueba que me indicaste, pero el error continua igual, la información se está cargando bien.

Comment: Habrá algun null en la consulta ? y crystal no lo está sabiendo entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado el error, jajaja, es que cuando escribí el código estaba un poco cansado.

Declaré la variable `ReportDocument` mal, esta sería la solución.

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
```

Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Bueno hombre, me alegro que por lo menos encontraras la solución al problema!